# How to use the same Bearer token sent by client, to authorise user against SecurityGroup using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am following this example https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless to authenticate user against Azure AD using user credentials (uname,pwd) to acquire a bearer access Token. This token will be sent in the Authorization header to the Rest API. The REST API uses the token to authorize the user using ClaimPrincipal.

Now, in my Rest API, I would want to validate if the user belongs to particular Security Group or not. For that purpose I need to use Graph API. But the problem is, every-time I pass the same Bearer Token to my Graph API, which the REST API has received from Client, it throws "Access Token Malformed" error.

In one of the sample (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) I found we need to regenerate a new Bearer Token to call Graph API, so do I need to re-generate a new Token to call Graph API? Couldn't I use the same Bearer Token which the client has send to my REST API, to call the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are like bank checks. A check written for you can only be cashed by you. If you want to call the graph from your web API, you can use the token you received as a starting point for getting a new token specifically for the graph. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/ for the pattern used in this case, you just need to substitute the custom API with the graph.

Comment: Hi Vittorio thx for the reply. As I mentioned earlier in the description of my question, I am already aware of this sample code  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/, but the problem I see is, I need to pass ClientID and AppSecret key again to recreate a new Token exclusively to call isMemberOf function of Graph API to verify if the user belongs to SecurityGroup or not.

Another solution I found was to update the manifest of the CloudService to include Group details in the bearer Token, but seems its restricted to include 200 groups

Comment: Sorry, I should have acknowledged in my answer that you did look at that sample. My hope was that the bank check analogy would have helped to look at that sample in a new light - bank checks might less convenient than cash, but they are more secure. A token whose audience is your service simply cannot be accepted by any other API than yours. I didn't mention the groups as claims given that the 200 groups cap requires you to be ready to fall back on calling the graph anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vibronet . Need ur help to verify if we are on the right track or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Need ur help to verify if we are on the right track or not.
1. User sends his credentials (uname,pwd) along with other detail to fetch Bearer Token from Azure AD (do we need to use ADFS instead? What would be the Azure OAuth URL if we decides to use it?)
2. User calls the REST API by including the Token as Auth header.
3. REST API uses ClaimPrinciple to validate if the request is coming from authenticated user.
4. Inside REST API, Graph API is called to check if User part of SecurityGroup or not.

Can step 1,2 be performed by using .pl, .py, js or REST Client?